# Sharepoint List Item View to Reflect Calendar View (How To?)

Tags: sharepoint

I have recurrence item in calendar, let's say it will repeat 5 times from start date 5/23/2018

In Calendar view, it will repeat the item from 5/23 to 5/28.

However in all item view(list view), it will only show once, it won't repeat the item 5 times.

Is there a way, to make list view replicate the calendar view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done using OOTB.

The best you get with OOTB is to create a view using view type **'Standard View, with Expanded Recurring Events."**:

- This will repeat the recurring item in the view
- However this will only show event from today onwards(will not show past events)

The other way will be to code manually

- It can be done using spservice and camlquery

```js
var camlQuery = "<Query><Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Year /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /></OrderBy></Query>";
var camlOptions = "<QueryOptions><RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion><ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence></QueryOptions>";
// Make the web service call to retrieve events.
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,
  listName: 'Test Calendar',
  CAMLQuery: camlQuery,
  CAMLQueryOptions: camlOptions,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('ows_title'))
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the view to "Current Events." In that view, recurrent events are displayed individually.

Comment: sorry, my question is how to display just like calendar. i don't want it to display individually,

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. On the All Items view, for the recurrent item you added, only one row is displayed. But when you switch to "Current Events" view, 5 rows are displayed. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, in "All view" or "custom view" i want the recurring event to be displayed 5 times (just like in calendar)

Comment: In the "All Events" or custom view, a recurring event is only displayed once. To view recurring events in multiple lines (like in Calendar), you can switch to "Current Events" view, or build your own view using code to retrieve and parse calendar items. Note that REST and CSOM do not have support for getting recurring data (more info at https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147117-provide-csom-and-rest-api-for-recurring-calendar-e). You'll need to use the old SOAP-based Lists Web Service (Lists.asmx).